# What is the use of the *~ files; are they some kind of default backup in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: filesystem, files, backup

I've noticed this *~ file gets created (hidden) whenever I edit a file; usually text document, scripts. Is it some kind of backup?!? as it seems so... However, I don't have a backup service configured for such...

So, are those files backup files? ...like for contents or attributes? If yes, how can use to restore/recover what the file has to offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit a file with `emacs` or `gedtit` usually those `*~` backup files are generated. Say you edit a file named `mytext.txt` then it would create a file nemed `mytext.txt~` which contains the buffer just before you edit it.

You can get back the un-edited version using in terminal

```
mv mytext.txt~ mytext.txt
```

It will revert back the changes. This happens for all the files that you can edit in text form.

I personally feel it quite annoying, to get rid of them you can set alias like,

```
alias cln='rm -i *~'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a backup. Your editor creates these apparently, you can configure it not to do so.

Comment: i guessed so... how do i use them... ideas would help... thanks...

Comment: They're just copies of the old content, you use them like the original :)